# Extracting pattern from multiple lines

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, latex

I have a file `test.tex` with content that is similar to this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Test}
\author{Author 1, Author 2, Author 3}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I want to extract every author that is written in the `{ ... }`. Therefore I did the following:

```
authors=$(cat test.tex | grep '\author' | tr -d '\author' | tr -d '{' | tr -d '}' )
```

This code works only for this case. My problem is that

1. there could be `[]` instead of `{}`
2. the line could span over multiple lines like the following example

`\author{Author 1,`

`Author 2,`

`Author 3}`

Does anyone know how to solve these two problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -nr '
/\\author/ {
    :ending
    /]|}$/! {
        N   
        b ending 
    }
    s/\\author(\{|\[)(.*)(}|])/\2/p
}
' test.tex
```

**Explanation (code the same, but comments added):**

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -nr '
# if the line contains the \author string, we are working with it.
/\\author/ {

    ##### this part are needed for multiple line pattern processing

    # put a label here. We will be return to this point, 
    # until we reach line, which have } or ] in the ending.
    :ending

    # if this line does not ended by } or ]. 
    # It is tell us, that this line continues on the next line.
    /]|}$/! {

        # Take the next line and append it to the previous line. 
        # Just join them together.
        N   

        # Go to the ":ending" label
        b ending 
    }

    ##### ending multiple line pattern processing

    # remove the \author word and brackets from line
    s/\\author(\{|\[)(.*)(}|])/\2/p
}
' test.tex
```

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Test}
\author{Author 1, Author 2, Author 3}
\author[Author 1, Author 2, Author 3]
\author{Author 1,
Author 2,
Author 3}
\author[Author 1,
Author 2,
Author 3]
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

**output**

```
Author 1, Author 2, Author 3
Author 1, Author 2, Author 3
Author 1,
Author 2,
Author 3
Author 1,
Author 2,
Author 3
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked and... I learned quite few from the explanation^^

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -zPo '\\author{\K[^}]*' ex1.tex | tr '\0\n' '\n '
```

Some quick explanation notes:

- `-z` input and output records ("lines") are separated by NULL (`\0`). So the full TeX file will be one single record.
- `-P` Use Perl pcre regular expression variant.
- `-o` output just the part of the record that matches the regExp.
- `\\author{\K` means left context

The `tr '\0\n'  '\n '`  changes the output record separator (`\0` to `\n`)
and removes NewLines inside names (`\n` to )

Comment: Would you mind explaining the command?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the job: `egrep -o '[\[{]?Author' | sed -E 's/[\[{]//'`

#### Examples:

1)

```
echo "\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Test}
\author[Author 1,
Author 2
Author 3 ] " | egrep -o '[\[{]?Author' | sed -E 's/[\[{]//'
Author
Author
Author
```

2)

```
echo "\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Test}
\author[Author 1, Author 2, Author 3]
\begin{document}
\end{document}" | egrep -o '[\[{]?Author' | sed -E 's/[\[{]//'
Author
Author
Author
```

3)

```
echo "\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Test}
\author{Author 1, Author 2, Author 3}
\begin{document}
\end{document}" | egrep -o '[\[{]?Author' | sed -E 's/[\[{]//'
Author
Author
Author
```

You can probably do it using only `grep` and lookbehinds and whatnot. I personally have no problems using a pipe into `sed` after `grep`.

Comment: This is close but not exactly. The author 1, author 2... Were supposed to be placeholder for actual names. (e.g. Author 1 = Ryan Banana) if you could change it so that that works too I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Python

With your input file as given in the question, one liner can be done as so:

```
$ python -c 'import sys,re;f=open(sys.argv[1],"r");a=tuple(l for l in f.readlines() if l.startswith("\\author") );print("\n".join(re.split(", |,|{|}",a[0].strip())[1:]))' input.tex      
Author 1
Author 2
Author 3
```

And a script as so:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys,re

# read the doc, find the desired line
line=""
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for l in f:
        if l.startswith("\\author"):
            line=l.strip()
            break
# split at multiple separators, get slice of that list starting since 2nd item
author_list = re.split( ", |,|{|}", line )[1:] 
# print 1 author per line
print("\n".join(author_list))
```

The key steps are two fold - read the file and find the line that stars with `\\authors` string, and then break the line at multiple separators into list of tokens, and build a new-line separated string out of that list of tokens. I also took the liberty to consider possibility that you may have to split either at `,` or `,<space>`.